# Convert from WriteFile to QtSerial write

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am trying to convert some old code to make use of the `QtSerial` integration.

I have the following:

```
void SendCmd(HANDLE Handle, UCHAR Address, UCHAR Command, UCHAR Type, UCHAR Motor, INT Value)
{

    UCHAR TxBuffer[9];
    DWORD BytesWritten;
    int i;

    TxBuffer[0]=Address;
    TxBuffer[1]=Command;
    TxBuffer[2]=Type;
    TxBuffer[3]=Motor;
    TxBuffer[4]=Value >> 24;
    TxBuffer[5]=Value >> 16;
    TxBuffer[6]=Value >> 8;
    TxBuffer[7]=Value & 0xff;
    TxBuffer[8]=0;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
        TxBuffer[8]+=TxBuffer[i];

    //Send the datagram

  WriteFile(Handle, TxBuffer, 9, &BytesWritten, NULL);
}
```

I want to use `QTSerial` for the handling of the port and the reading/sending of data. Im in a little over my head. For the handling I currently have:

```
HANDLE OpenRS2322(const wchar_t* ComName, DWORD BaudRate)
{
    HANDLE ComHandle;
    DCB CommDCB;
    COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeouts;
    ComHandle=CreateFileW(ComName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_SUCCESS) return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    else
    {
        GetCommState(ComHandle, &CommDCB);

        CommDCB.BaudRate=BaudRate;
        CommDCB.Parity=NOPARITY;
        CommDCB.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
        CommDCB.ByteSize=8;

        CommDCB.fBinary=1;  //Binary Mode only
        CommDCB.fParity=0;
        CommDCB.fOutxCtsFlow=0;
        CommDCB.fOutxDsrFlow=0;
        CommDCB.fDtrControl=0;
        CommDCB.fDsrSensitivity=0;
        CommDCB.fTXContinueOnXoff=0;
        CommDCB.fOutX=0;
        CommDCB.fInX=0;
        CommDCB.fErrorChar=0;
        CommDCB.fNull=0;
        CommDCB.fRtsControl=RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE;
        CommDCB.fAbortOnError=0;

        SetCommState(ComHandle, &CommDCB);

        //Set buffer size
        SetupComm(ComHandle, 100, 100);

        //Set up timeout values (very important, as otherwise the program will be very slow)
        GetCommTimeouts(ComHandle, &CommTimeouts);

        CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout=MAXDWORD;
        CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier=0;
        CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant=0;

        SetCommTimeouts(ComHandle, &CommTimeouts);

        return ComHandle;
  }
}
```

and when I send a command I use (for example):

```
HANDLE RS232Handle;
    RS232Handle=OpenRS232(COM5, 9600);
    SendCmd(RS232Handle, 1, 5, 154, 5, 0);
    CloseRS232(RS232Handle);
```

I have run into some problems using the above code in QT. Like asynchronously reading issues.

My lame attempt to modify the above code to use `QSerialPort`:

For the handle of the port:

```
QSerialPort serial;
    serial.setPortName("COM5");
    serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::HardwareControl);
    if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable())
    {
    qDebug() << "Serial is open";
      }
```

and for the actual writing of data that is previously being sent via `WriteFile`, I don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since `QSerialPort` extends from `QIODevice`, just use the `read` and `write` methods to send and receive data from the port.  In this regard, the `QSerialPort` acts just like any other file that you open with Qt.  When you write out something to the serial port, the easiest way to to simply put your data into a `QByteArray` and then write that out.  Something like the following should work:

```
void SendCmd(QSerialPort* port, UCHAR Address, UCHAR Command, UCHAR Type, UCHAR Motor, INT Value)
{

QByteArray ba;
UCHAR checksum = 0;

ba.append(Address);
ba.append(Command);
ba.append(Type);
ba.append(Motor);
ba.append(Value >> 24;
ba.append(Value >> 16);
ba.append(Value >> 8);
ba.append(Value & 0xff);
for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    checksum += ba[i];
ba.append( checksum );

//Send the datagram
port->write( ba );
}
```

Note that at this point, the data has probably not been written to the device(that happens once the control goes back to the main loop).

To read the data, create a slot that connects to the `readyRead` signal of the serial port.  This signal is emitted when there is some data to be read from the port.  A simple implementation may look like this:

```
/* When the seral port is made */
/* (using new signal/slot syntax) */
connect( serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead,
         this, &MyClass::readyRead );

/* ... other initialization code ... */

void MyClass::readyRead(){
    QByteArray data = serialPort.readAll();

    /* Data processing here */
}
```